# Does doc_count include doc_del_count for /db call

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

When I do a [Get /{db}](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/common.html#get--db) call, CouchDb documentation states the following:

- `doc_count` (number) – A count of the documents in the specified database.
- `doc_del_count` (number) – Number of deleted documents

Does this mean `doc_count` excludes deleted document count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc_count` excludes deleted documents. This is easily verified -- I created a new database via the Cloudant dashboard, created 4 documents and deleted 1. So:

```
curl -s 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/blaha/_all_docs'
    {"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
       {"id":"3a4a3dc11a24e9aaa7e92688226e24f8","key":"3a4a3dc11a24e9aaa7e92688226e24f8","value":{"rev":"1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"}},
       {"id":"b5f7d2935bc061fc0b5757223a02adf3","key":"b5f7d2935bc061fc0b5757223a02adf3","value":{"rev":"1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"}},
       {"id":"b5f7d2935bc061fc0b5757223a02ec08","key":"b5f7d2935bc061fc0b5757223a02ec08","value":{"rev":"1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"}}
    ]}
```

and (output trimmed for brevity):

```
curl -s 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/blaha' | jq .
{
    "db_name": "blaha",
    "doc_del_count": 1,
    "doc_count": 3,
    "disk_size": 202240,
    "data_size": 4499,
}
```